# Magento modules with only Ajax Controller

Tags: ajax, magento-1.6

I'd like to create a new module with just AjaxController. Do I need anyway to have a layout ?
I mean here is my file and code :

`/var/www/html/dev/app/code/local/NameSpace/Cart/controllers/AjaxController.php`

```
class NameSpace_Cart_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function quickbuyAction()
    {
        return json_encode(array('ok' => true));
    }
}
```

`/var/www/html/dev/app/code/local/NameSpace/Cart/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NameSpace_Cart>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </NameSpace_Cart>
    </modules>
    <global>
    </global>
</config>
```

When i tried to call my url `localhost/cart/ajax/quickbuy`, its returned me a 404.
Do I miss something ?

And yes I declared my xml in the `app/etc/modules` folder.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please read this and follow the steps http://stackoverflow.com/a/588683/4155637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NameSpace_Cartevent>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </NameSpace_Cartevent>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <NameSpace_cartevent>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>NameSpace_Cartevent</module>
                    <frontName>cartevent</frontName>
                </args>
            </NameSpace_cartevent>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>`

My mistake : When i tried the first time, i put the `<frontend>` tag in the `<global>` tag but it has to be outside the `<global>` tag.

Thx for you links @Arunendra.